# Why I am advised to use pointer in Quick Sort?

Tags: c++

I wrote Quick Sort in CPP,  it is working fine. But when I checked with Google Coding standards it is advising this. I am not able to decipher this message, can you please explain what is wrong with my code.

```
qs.cpp:8:  Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer: std::vector<int> &A  [runtime/references] [2]
qs.cpp:9:  Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer: std::vector<int> &A  [runtime/references] [2]
qs.cpp:25:  Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer: std::vector<int> &A  [runtime/references] [2]
qs.cpp:34:  Is this a non-const reference? If so, make const or use a pointer: std::vector<int> &A  [runtime/references] [2]
Done processing qs.cpp
Total errors found: 4

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

void quickSort(std::vector<int> &A, int p, int r);
int partition(std::vector<int> &A, int p, int r);

int main() {
  std::vector<int> a = {2, 8, 7, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4};
  std::cout << std::setw(10) << "UnSorted Array:\n"
  for (int ele : a) {
    std::cout << ele << std::setw(5);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::setw(10) << "Sorted Array:\n";
  quickSort(a, 0, a.size()-1);
  for (int ele : a) {
    std::cout << ele << std::setw(5);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void quickSort(std::vector<int> &A, int p, int r) {
  int q;
  if ( p  < r ) {
    q = partition(A, p, r);
    quickSort(A, p, q-1);
    quickSort(A, q+1, r);
  }
}

int partition(std::vector<int> &A, int p, int r) {
  int x = A[r];
  int i = p-1;
  for (int j = p; j < r; j++) {
    if (A[j] <= x) {
      i = i+1;
      std::swap(A[i], A[j]);
    }
  }
  std::swap(A[i+1], A[r]);
  return i+1;
}
```

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299021/non-optional-pointers-vs-non-const-references-in-c has the answer. Anyway, the Google style doc is not a standard one and never will be as many cpp programmers don't stick to it for good reasons.

Comment: Personally I think there is nothing wrong with a non const reference and it beautifies the code.

Comment: Please don't use Googles coding standards as an authoritative source of "good practice. They are written by Google, for Google, to manage their huge repository of both new and legacy code and give some uniformity. They are (In *my* oppinion) *not* a good example of modern C++ best practices.

Comment: Nothing bad is wrong with your code. But the Google Style Guide forbids a lot of features that Google internally can't use. I personally wouldn't use it as a style guide.

Comment: Google engineers apparently get confused by `std::swap`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @all - So what you think is best coding standard out there? Say I am writing some code for a book, and I just want to make sure it is conforming to some standards(So I choose Google coding standards). After some comments here, I am thinking other coding standards. Is there any thing like https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html for modern cpp development ?

Comment: @PeteBecker - agree !

Comment: You are at much greater liberty when it comes to coding standards when you are writing a book, you can focus solely on expressiveness, elegance and all that, why not invent one yourself?

Answer (score 1):

There is an opinion, apparently shared by Google, that non-const references are bad because they make it non-obvious at the call site that the argument is going to be modified by the call.